# How can I merge excel row by grouping their top row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a difficult excel case as image below

[image]

Question is how can I convert to this format ?

[image]

Comment: FYI, this can be done through PowerQuery in a few very easy steps.

Comment: I'm new in PowerQuery. Could you please give some guide how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this one is probably pretty dirty, but it does what you need:

[image]

Formula in D2: `=IF(B2="";D1;B2)`
Formula in E2: `=IF(D2=D3;"";D2)`
Formula in F2: `=IF(D2=D1;F1&C2;C2)`

You can filter in column E, to get only the rows you want (or delete the no wanted ones **after** pasting values)

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely what I looking for. Brilliant logic thinking.. Thanks and appreciate so much, bro